# div is rendered first few seconds even if ng-if is false in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

So I'm trying to hide a navbar when on the login page. I've put the navbar inside a nav-element, and putted a "ng-if" in the element to only render if the user is in the application(and not the login page).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demoapp">
<head>
    <!-- Angular & jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script><!-- load jquery -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script><!-- load angular -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script><!-- load ngRoute -->
</head>
<body>
    <nav ng-if=false>
    /... nav elements inside here
    </nav>

    <!-- to load ngRoute-->
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

But when I'm on the login page, the navbar still shows up for a second, and then disappears. Why is it doing that? How do I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According AngularJS documentation "The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the AngularJS html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading. Use this directive to avoid the undesirable flicker effect caused by the html template display.

The directive can be applied to the  element, but the preferred usage is to apply multiple ngCloak directives to small portions of the page to permit progressive rendering of the browser view."

Please refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Good answer I think, but I have not solved with your answer. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866811/ng-repeat-is-rendering-both-of-previous-and-current-value-few-seconds-and-disapp

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) is for:

```
<nav ng-cloak ng-if=false>
/... nav elements inside here
</nav>
```

Comment: Good answer I think, but I have not solved with your answer. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866811/ng-repeat-is-rendering-both-of-previous-and-current-value-few-seconds-and-disapp

Answer (score 1):

Add `ng-cloak` to your `body` tag, this will prevent glitching for ALL elements that have an `ng-if` attribute attached to them.

Comment: Good answer I think, but I have not solved with your answer. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866811/ng-repeat-is-rendering-both-of-previous-and-current-value-few-seconds-and-disapp